# How do I create a parameter in the console of AWS Data Pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-data-pipeline

I'd like to define some parameters in the console of AWS DataPipeline, but am not able to do so. The parameters are going to be called in a SqlActivity, so when I try to refer to them in the in-line SQL script and save the pipeline, I'm getting error messages saying that no such parameters exist. The parameters page is blank and I can't find the button to make one. 
Google results are all showing me how to create parameterized pipelines, which is not what I'm exactly looking for

Answer (score 4):

At the moment, you cannot create parameter objects from the AWS Datapipeline console. Please use aws cli to create a pipeline definition with parameter objects.

Comment: Five years later, in 2020, this is still not supported...

Comment: Wow really? If I remember correctly, you can do it by uploading a JSON file to create a pipeline but have no idea if that functionality has been removed/deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for "adding" parameters to your pipeline by creating another one almost identical.

Go to your pipeline definition and click `Export`. Copy paste the json content to a file on your local machine. In the last rows of the json, find the `parameters`, here is where you will add as many params as you wish. I will leave a snippet:

```
    "parameters": [
    {
      "description": “Description example“,
      "id": “myVar1”,
      "myComment": “Comment“,
      "type": "String"
    }
    ],
    "values": {
      “myVar1": “data”
    }
```

Next time you create the pipeline: `Create pipeline -> Source -> Import a definition -> <your_json_definition>`